# How do I move a new Outlook task into a non-default task folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've created a task folder, "Certification Requests", that is not connected to my primary tasks folder, which is tied to my inbox.

I want new tasks that my VBA creates to drop into the new folder, rather than my primary task list.

I have code but the tasks are creating in my primary task list. This script is running based upon a rule.

```vb
Sub CreateNewTask(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewTask As TaskItem
    
    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewTask = obApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    
    With NewTask
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .Body = Item.Body
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .Save
    End With
    
    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewTask = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure that's what i'm looking for exactly. My VBA already creates the task, but it creates it in the default task folder when I'm wanting it to be created in another folder. I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, and maybe your answer gives that to me. However, I may need more hand-holding if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `Move` the `NewTask` to the folder in question.

```
Sub CreateNewTask(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("johndoe@outlook.com").Folders("Certification Requests")
    Set NewTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

    With NewTask
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .Body = Item.Body
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .Save
        .Move myFolder
    End With
End Sub
```

Alternately, you could `Add` a new task item in the folder.

```
Sub CreateNewTask(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("johndoe@outlook.com").Folders("Certification Requests")
    Set NewTask = myFolder.Items.Add(olTaskItem)

    With NewTask
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .Body = Item.Body
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .Save
    End With
End Sub
```

You may have to modify the `Set myFolder = …` based on where your the "Certification Requests" folder is in the folder hierarchy).